# NSSavePanel's AccessoryView sometimes disabled

Tags: cocoa

I tried to add a AccessoryView to a NSSavePanel but sometimes the AccessoryView (it's elements) is disables and sometimes not. Hopefully anyone has a idea.

Here is my code:

```
    NSWindow *window = [[NSApp delegate] window];

// Get savePath
NSSavePanel *spanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];

__block SaveAccessoryViewController *saveAccessoryViewController = [[SaveAccessoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SaveAccessoryView" bundle:nil];

[spanel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"pdf"]];
[spanel setAccessoryView:saveAccessoryViewController.view];

[spanel beginSheetModalForWindow:window completionHandler:^(NSInteger returnCode) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I concluded that it had to do with ARC (Automatic Reference Count) settings for the project.

If you are using ARC make sure the settings are correct both on project and target.

In my case I had enabled ARC on target but not on project, after enabling ARC on project (and dealing with resulting errors and warnings) everything works perfectly now.